# Why my drivers use 4.2 TB of physical memory?

Tags: memory, process-explorer

[image]

So I got this info from Process Explorer (System Information window -> Memory)... I have 32 GB of RAM installed. How could drivers use 4 TB, while Kernel only 8 KB?

Comment: First update Process Explorer. I have PE 16.43 here and the Driver screen you show displays properly and normally. After updating PE, restart and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/584045/processexplorer-display-huge-number-in-34driver-ws.html) Microsoft Docs, which links to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180719234227/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=246) archived webpage, Windows 8.1 changed some address space layouts, introducing quirks. I don't understand the rest, but it may be useful to you. The drivers cannot be using 4 terabytes, though; your physical memory (as listed in the Total category) is only approximately 32 GB.